# Arithmetic time and work problem

Tags: arithmetic

8 children can do a work in 12 days whereas 6 adults can do it in 8 days.  If among 12 adults ,8 adults leave work, 2 days after starting a work and 16 children join work instead.  Then how many days will it take to do the rest work?

I can't solve it. I have tried for 2 hours. Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Simply compute the working speed of each adult and child.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the question. If $6$ adults can complete the task in $3$ days then $12$ adults can complete it in $\frac 3 2$ days, which is less than $2$ days.

Comment: Oh sorry. I've edited.

Comment: Well, $8~\text{children}\times 12~\text{days}\times R~\text{jobs completed per child per day} = 1~\text{completed job}$.  Dividing we can find $R$.  We have that $R~\text{jobs completed per child per day} = \frac{1}{96}~\text{job per child per day}$, meaning that if a single child works for one day then $\frac{1}{96}$'th of a job will have been completed.  Similarly, if $96$ children work together for a single day, one full job will have been completed, etc...  Do something similar for the adults.  Find out what proportion of the job will have been completed by a single adult in a single day

Comment: You will be able to find then how much of the job has been completed at the end of the two-day period and how much of the job remains and through proper manipulation be able to find out how much time is required for the remaining adults and children to finish what work is left.

Comment: So 4 children can do a work in 24 days, 3 adults can do a work in 16 days. If among 6 adults, 4 leave work, 4 days after starting a work,  and 8 children join work instead. Then how many days will it take to do the rest. This is the rescaled problem, under the assumption days to do something is inversely proportional to the number of people working on it. Oh and all people of the same type do the same amount of work.  have fun ...

Answer (score 2):

In $12$ days $8$ children will complete $12 \times 8 = 96$ child-days of work.

In $8$ days $6$ adults will complete $8 \times 6 = 48$ adult-days of work.

So $96$ child-days is the same as $48$ adult-days. In other words, $2$ children work at the same rate as $1$ adult.

So the $16$ children who join the team are working at the same rate as the $8$ adults who left after $2$ days.

I'll let you take it from there.